# Unable to release Jenkins plugin to jenkins-ci.org

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I want to publish my [display-console-output-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/display-console-output-plugin/).

But I got an error message saying `ssh: Could not resolve hostname lyenliang: Name or service not known` when executing `mvn release:prepare release:perform -Dusername=lyenliang -Dpassword=myPassword`, where `lyenliang` is my github account.

You can find more information about the above command [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hosting+Plugins).

This error message comes from `cmd.exe /X /C "git push lyenliang:********@github.com:jenkinsci/display-console-output-plugin.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"`.

I don't understand why I still get this error I have successfully [requested upload permission](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/repository-permissions-updater/pull/289).

Why does it say that my github account is not a valid name?

You can visit [here](https://gist.github.com/lyenliang/383edfff7a9c4fd9f8ed22dec8ff3acc) for more error messages.

Here's the settings.xml I have:

```
<settings>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.jenkins-ci.tools</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>

  <profiles>
    <!-- Give access to Jenkins plugins -->
    <profile>
      <id>jenkins</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> <!-- change this to false, if you don't like to have it on per default -->
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
          <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
          <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
      <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
      <mirrorOf>m.g.o-public</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Comment: Do you have a network proxy set in your settings.xml?

Comment: @EssexBoy, No, I don't have a network proxy set in my settings.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting my github username and password into `settings.xml`(See [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hosting+Plugins) for how to put them into this file), then executing `mvn release:prepare release:perform`.

The `git push` command inside this method then becomes `cmd.exe /X /C "git push git@github.com:jenkinsci/display-console-output-plugin.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"`. It executed with no errors.

However, I still don't know why putting my github account and password in the command line doesn't work. I use the same account and password for both github and jenkins-ci.org.